# Vector of pointers to possibly nonexistent objects

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I have an object `A`, that I want to wrap with a list of objects (pointers to objects) of type `B`, that `A` should process.

The problem is, that some of `B` objects can be deleted and `A` doesn't know about it. I know I can handle it with exceptions, but I would rather to avoid it.

Full problem: I'm writing C++ SFML project, I want to wrap a `sf::RenderWindow` with a vector of `sf::Drawable *` pointers to objects, that window should draw. And problem is the same. Some of `sf::Drawable` objects may be already deleted, but `sf::RenderWindow` tries to use it.

I can possibly cancel the idea of wrapping, but if there a good design solution, it would be great.

Comment: Isn't that a case for `std::weak_ptr`?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap with a list of objects"? What does "wrap" mean in this context?

Comment: @user0042 `std::weak_ptr` will be quite slow.

Comment: @Galik is `weak_ptr` really that slow? You'll need something that can track the object lifetime separate from the object itself to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom weak_ptr locks a mutex before you can use it so iterating over a list would incur some overhead. You only need to do that if you require *shared ownership*. As far as I can tell that is not the case here. You can simply set the pointer to `nullptr` to indicate it has been deleted.

Comment: @Galik I read "and A doesn't know about it" to mean that the pointers can't be nulled because whoever is deleting the objects doesn't have access to those pointers.

Comment: "I know I can handle it with exceptions" - no you can't. Using an object that has been deleted is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to throw any kind of exception.

Comment: @Galik I meant, I want to write a class C, that incapsulates object A together with list of B. Then i would just use C  to add/remove pointers to B objects from this list via interface, but A doesn't know, which pointers are alive/dead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which will return `true` or `false` in an `if()` statement depending if it has been deleted or not:

```
// use a std::unique_ptr that will record if its target has been deleted
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>> drawables;

// deleting an element

for(auto& drawable: drawables)
{
    if(needs_to_be_deleted(drawable.get()))
        drawable.reset(); // deletes object
}

// process elements

for(auto& drawable: drawables)
{
    if(drawable) // returns false if element is deleted
    {
        // pass by reference or pointer (using get())
        do_something_with_drawable(drawable.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure memory is not reused, as it will result in undefined behavior if the object is no longer live when you use it.

Create a map for the live objects, and only use value, if it is still in the map